# How to prevent the slash added after the # sign

Tags: c#, iis, umbraco

Basically, I have a website which needs to be accessible, so I implemented something called Skip Links, By pressing tab on the keyboard when entering the page it has been made possible to navigate the page by appending a target to the URL and scrolling to the target.

I have multiple headings in the page with ids, such as #maincontent, #personalArea and so on.

To navigate to them i simply navigate to website.com/#mainContent or website.com#mainContent.

When I try to do that it automatically gets changed to website.com/#/mainContent, and then stays on the current page without scrolling me to the target, I tried using the following rewrite module, but to no avail.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!--To always remove trailing slash from the URL-->
    <rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)/$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

How can I disable the automatically added slash preceding the # sign?

Its important to note I am running on Umbraco v7 on IIS 10, I don't know if Umbraco might be responsible for this strange occurrence.

Comment: Anything after a `#` symbol doesn't even get passed to the server so your rewrite rules won't have any affect. When you say you are trying to do this "automatically", what do you mean?

Comment: @DavidG If i manually enter site.com#content it takes me to site.com/#/content

Comment: That can only be some Javascript doing that, have you added anything that might affect the URL? Do you use something like Angular for example?

Comment: @DavidG Indeed I do use angularjs 1.5, but I do not use angular for routing.

Comment: Looks like Angular is taking over the `#` anchors

Comment: It seems that you will have to set html5mode to true: https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Comment: @MarioLopez Initially I though it worked, but then I noticed none of the links worked, the skip links work I cant move from page to page, it changes the url but doesen't reload page or really take me there.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing your full angular code.